# Mysql ошибка в запросе UPDATE

Tags: mysql, update

Всем доброго времени суток!
Прошу помочь разобраться.
Есть две таблицы:

**documents1**

| id | doc_id | row_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 555 |

**documents2**

| id | doc_id | doc_num | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 888 |  |

Нужно апдейтить type во второй таблицу по сл. условиям:

1. Если doc_num <> doc_id и в первой таблице по этому doc_id row_id не пустая, то тип 1
2. Иначе тип 2

Составила примерно запрос, но он неточный.

```
UPDATE document2 SET type = IF( `doc_num` <> `doc_id` AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM document1 RIGHT JOIN document2 USING(doc_id) WHERE row_id <> "") > 0, 1, 2);
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, доработать.

Comment: *Составила примерно запрос, но он неточный.* Он вообще бредовый. [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual/../UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) - читать "Multiple-table syntax".

Comment: Забыла написать, что на сервере версия 5

Comment: *и в первой таблице по этому doc_id row_id не пустая* `COUNT()` для этого не нужен - есть оператор EXISTS.

Comment: *на сервере версия 5* Значит, ту же статью для пятой версии. Там разницы практически нет.

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось!